# Java Tree Recursion parameter issues

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am attempting to give a void function to a Tree. It calculates some parameters and uses Ids  to reference some coordinates and the distance between them. The problem I have is that every recursion call returns me 0 on both parameters I use, I thought in Java every variable was a reference so this would work, but  I seem to be missing something. Here is the code:

```
public void volumeandcost(Integer  volume,Float cost){
    if(children().equals(0)){//children() returns the number of children our tree has
        volume=volume+getCapacidad(this.root);//root is the Id
    }
    else{//recursive call
        ArrayList<Integer> myvol= new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Float> mycost=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<this.children();i++){
            myvol.add(new Integer(0));
            mycost.add(new Float(0.0));                
            children.get(i).volumeandcost(myvol.get(i), mycost.get(i));
            cost=cost+mycost.get(i)+myvol.get(i)*
                  square(ProbIA5Board.m_dist.get(this.root).get(this.children.get(i).getId()));
        }
        //this calculates our volume in case we have children
        volume=min(getCapacidad(root)*3,mysum(myvol)+getCapacidad(root));
    }
}
```

I call this function with both parameters initially set at 0, and they come back in the same way after the call to volumeandcost.

After following some advice I implemented a new class Pair like this:

```
public class Pair {
Integer vol;Float cost;
public Pair (){this.vol=new Integer(0);this.cost=new Float(0);}
Integer getVol(){ return this.vol;}
Float getCost(){ return this.cost;}
void setVol(Integer x){this.vol=x ;}
void setCost(Float x){this.cost=x ;}
void addVol(Integer x){this.vol=this.vol+x;}
    void addCost(Float x){this.cost=this.cost+x;}
}
```

and modified the function so that it's like this:

```
    public void volumeandcostp(Pair p){
    if(children().equals(0)){
        p.setVol(p.getVol() + getCapacidad(this.root));//tenemos el volumen
    }
    else{//recursion
        ArrayList<Pair> myvol= new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<this.children();i++){
            myvol.add(new Pair());                
            children.get(i).volumeandcostp(myvol.get(i));
            myvol.get(i).getCost());
            p.addCost(myvol.get(i).getCost()+ myvol.get(i).getVol()*                            square(ProbIA5Board.m_dist.get(this.root).get(this.children.get(i).getId())));
        }              p.setVol(min(getCapacidad(root)*3,mysump(myvol)+getCapacidad(root)));
    }   
}
```

But all the getters from Pair keep giving me 0 as answer.

Comment: But `volume` and `cost` are **parameters**. In Java they don't work bidirectional... Java works with *call-by-value*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value As your parameters are actually passed by value, you only change the local copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought in Java every variable was a reference.

First of all that statement is **wrong**: you have [primitive types](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html) like `int`, `float`, `char`. Those are **not references** to begin with. But indeed variables with types other than those eight are references.

But when you **call a function**, Java does a *call-by-value*. That means the **references are copied**. When you call: `volumeandcost(a,b)`. Java will make a copy of the reference. So `volume` and `cost` **work independently**. *Setting* them (i.e. assigning a new value to them) in your method has no effect.

You can *alter the state* of the objects you are given: since you copy the reference `a` refers to the *same object* as `volume` (in the example above), you can call methods on the objects the references refer to and alter the state, but you **cannot change the reference itself**.

Comment: I see, past experiences with Java and Android made me think that.

Comment: You last paragraph confuses me a little. Does that mean that if Integer had a sum function that did exactly what '+' does volume would be calculated correctly?

Comment: @GuillemMarquésdeTrasobares: an `Integer is (like a `Float`, `String`, etc.) an immtable object: it means you cannot alter the state. But if it had a method to *alter* its state, you could indeed communicate through it (but that is not the case).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As provided in other answers, you can only alter the state of the objects when you pass them to a method- Java is call by value.
Consider this instead of Integers :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println( "Before adding size is " + list.size() );
modifyList(list);
System.out.println( "After adding size is " + list.size() ); 

public void modifyList( List<Integer> list )
{
   list.add( 5 );
}
```

Why do you see the `list.size()` modified ? Because `list`'s state is modified not the original reference to list itself, the copied reference that passed to method played with a method called `add` and modified the state of object it refers to. So when you call `size()` using original reference , you will get the updated state of the object.

Now, to tackle your problem, you could do it with devising your own class, some thing like :

```
class Metrics
{
   Integer volume;
   Float cost;
}
```

Pass `Metrics` to your new method and update the fields `volume`, `cost` inside your method.